# Using Python's Easyguy to pick files with fileopenbox, how can I limit the user to selecting ONLY one file-type, such as '.csv' or 'pkl'

Tags: python, user-interface

Using Python's Easyguy to pick files with fileopenbox, when setting `filetypes = ['*.pkl']`, the option to choose pkl files is added to the list of allowed file extensions, however it is added below the option '*.*' (All file types) which is at the top of this list, and therefore the user can pick any file with any extension. I would like the user to be able to pick only .pkl files.

Code:

`import easygui`

`a=easygui.fileopenbox(msg='ty message', title='a_title', default='../../../results/raw_data/2020-06-29_20x30_demo/', filetypes=['*.pkl'], multiple=False)`

[Image of the GUI that appears with the above code. The drop-down list near the text 'Files of type' has the option 'All files (*.*)' at the top, and therefore it is the default. using the `filetypes =['*.pkl']` option populates this dropdown list with the option to pick only pkl data. But this is not the default presented to the user.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnXmv.png)

I would like to know if there is a solution for this with Easygui or another library should be used.

Thanks!!